# Merging different parts of one file - based on a variable in the file

Tags: spss

I have a data file that looks like the first picture, I am reading it in to SPSS using `FILE TYPE MIXED` so that it looks like the second picture. How can I merge the cases based on the ID variable so that cases with the same ID variable are merged? The variable `Age` is repeated, so it does not matter which is selected, but it would be good if it were possible to select the first value.

[image: Diagram]

Here is an example of the code I am using to read the data:

```
FILE TYPE MIXED RECORD=RecordID 1
    / WILD =WARN.
RECORD TYPE 1.
DATA LIST
    / ID 8-9 JobType 3-4 Age 5-7.
RECORD TYPE 2.
DATA LIST
    / ID 3-4 Sex 11 Salary 5-8.
RECORD TYPE 3.
DATA LIST
    / ID 6-7 Age 8-10 Hiring 3-5.
END FILE TYPE.
BEGIN DATA
1  1 39 1
1  3 27 2
1  2 27 3
1  3 25 4
2 1 9000  0
2 2 7500  0
2 3 4750  1
2 4 7250  1
3  76 1 39
3  98 2 27
3   8 3 27
3  44 4 25
END DATA.
LIST.
```

Comment: what should be done with the repeating `age` variable? do you want to just select one of them for the result data?

Comment: Good question, I forgot to mention that. It doesn't matter in this case which is used because they are both the same, but if the first one (i.e. the one nearer the top) is selected that would be better for future use. I've edited the question now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
sort cases by ID RecordID.
casestovars id=ID/index=RecordID.
```

If the ages are identical they collapse into one column. If they aren't, you'll get three `age` columns, and you'll be able to choose the one you prefer.